# Given three positive numbers $x,y,z$ so that $xyz=1, xy+yz+zx=5$. Find the maximum value $x^{c}+ y^{c}+ z^{c}$ for $c\geqq -1$ .

Tags: inequality, permutations, symmetry, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, constants

> Given three positive numbers $x, y, z$ so that $xyz= 1, xy+ yz+ zx= 5$. find the maximum value
>   $$x^{c}+ y^{c}+ z^{c}$$
>   for $c\geqq -1$ .

I think that the equality occurs at $x= y= 2, z= 1\div 4$ and its cyclic permutation. from hypothesis :
$$5= xy+ yz+ zx\geqq 2\sqrt{x}+ \frac{1}{x}\therefore 2.4\geqq \sqrt{x}\geqq 0.5$$
from that, we have
$$x^{c}+ y^{c}+ z^{c}\geqq x^{c}+ \frac{2}{x^{c}}$$
after that, we can use *weight a.m.-g.m.* to determine $c= constant$ but this way's only true for $c< 0$

I need to the help

Comment: Given the conditions,  one of $x,y,z$ must be greater than $1.$ so if $c$ is really unbounded above, then so is $x^x+y^c+z^c.$

Comment: Oh ! I see that